# For a specific point in space, get the pixel in which that point lies (in R)

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sp

I am a bit new to the spatial packages of R. I have a hdf file from which I can get a data.frame with the latitude and longitude of the corners of the pixels, and the latitude and longitude of the centre of the pixel.

I have a specific point, and I would like to figure out which pixel covers that point.

Is there some function for this? what would be the best approach?

Comment: I think this question would be more suitable for https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @snair1591 should I change it by myself or the admins will do it?

Comment: Admins won't post the question for you, they'll either downvote or flag. And it's better you post the question  as people in GIS would be more helpful for this problem.

Comment: can I cancel/erase this question? Thank you

Comment: I don't think you have to. If you get a solution there, just post a link to that as your answer. But if you want, you do have the option to delete your question.